# How to retrain a sagemaker model on new data, after a training job is created

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, pre-trained-model

I have a sagemaker model that is trained on a specific dataset, and training job is created. Now i have a new dataset that the model has to be trained on, how do I retrain the model on new data from the already existing model ? Can we have the model checkpoints saved ?

Comment: did u get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only three built-in algorithms currently support incremental training: Object Detection Algorithm, Image Classification Algorithm, and Semantic Segmentation Algorithm.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/incremental-training.html

Comment: Thanks, that was useful! I'm also looking at how to automate the batch transform job, using an existing training job through a lambda function, any pointers as to how :)